# Ajax Error datatables.net/tn/7

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a project created on PHP laravel, and I'm immplementig Ajax on all my options that have datatables, I was working fine but somehow my Ajax stop working and don't know why.

When I select and option on my web site with a Datatable shows the mesage:

```
Datatables warning: table id=example - Ajax error. For more 
information aboute this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7
```

And don't show my content tables. When I select right click->inspect element show the mesage:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded http://tienda.local.com/ajax/getJSONResultsForDT?table=tipos&primaryKey=id&…art=0&length=10&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&_=1423606401783
```

Network

```
Request URL:http://tienda.local.com/ajax/getJSONResultsForDT?table=tipos&primaryKey=id&draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=id&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=clave_tipo&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=nombre_tipo&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=created_at&columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B4%5D%5Bdata%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B5%5D%5Bdata%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&order%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=3&order%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=desc&start=0&length=10&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&_=1423606554946
```

I don't know what is that bug.

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {

    oDtable = $('#example').dataTable({
        "scrollY": 300,
        "order": [3, 'desc'],
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "tableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            "aButtons": ["copy", "xls", "csv", "print"]
        },
        "ajax": "/ajax/getJSONResultsForDT?table=tipos&primaryKey=id",
        "columns": [
            {"data": "id"},
            {"data": "clave_tipo"},
            {"data": "nombre_tipo"},
            {"data": "created_at"},
            {"data": null},
            {"data": null}
        ],
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [0],
                "visible": false
            },
            {
                "targets": [4],
                "orderable": false,
                "data": null,
                "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    return '<a data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-info" href="tipos/' + data.id + '/edit" data-target="#myModal">EDITAR</a>';
                }
            },
            {
                "targets": [5],
                "orderable": false,
                "data": null,
                "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    var urlFormated = ''+data.nombre_tipo+'';
                    var encodedUrl = encodeURIComponent(urlFormated);              
                    return '<a data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-danger" href="/delete?id=' + data.id + '&nombre=tipos&nombretipo='+encodedUrl+'" data-target="#myModalDestroy">ELIMINAR</a>';
                }
            }],
        "bPaginate": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "language": {
            "url": "assets/js/DataTables-1.10.0/lang/" + "<?php echo $lang; ?>" + ".lang"
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">

<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>CLAVE TIPO</th>
        <th>NOMBRE TIPO</th>
        <th>FECHA CREACION</th>
        <th>EDITAR</th>
        <th>ELIMINAR</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Any help will be grateful!

Comment: Can you add the method type for your ajax call in your datatable? e.g $('#example').dataTable( {
  "ajax": {
    "url": "data.json",
    "type": "POST"
  }
} ); These kinds of issues,based on my experience with DTs are all client-server communication through ajax.

Comment: And also check the response being thrown back to the client. Use firebug or some web developer tool